youtube_player_flutter loading infinitely
im using 3 packages youtube_player_flutter for opening youtube video, flutter_inappwebview for docx file view, flutter_widget_from_html for html string i get from api. the issue is when i open youtube playing it playing inifinite loading bcoz of (flutter_widget_from_html) this package when i comment that package and click pub get youtube player starts working normally

I/WebViewFactory( 7593): Loading com.google.android.webview version 113.0.5672.136 (code 567263634)
W/ziparchive( 7593): Unable to open '/data/app/~~rgmIxc2DY0-4clEmnK66yw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_567263634-qRIuE-Za-SAV0_DzaiZQHw==/TrichromeLibrary.dm': No such file or directory
W/ziparchive( 7593): Unable to open '/data/app/~~rgmIxc2DY0-4clEmnK66yw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_567263634-qRIuE-Za-SAV0_DzaiZQHw==/TrichromeLibrary.dm': No such file or directory
W/rm.students_krm( 7593): Entry not found

and more

Please explain clearly how you're using these packages to do what you want to do.  As it stands, your question isn't clear whether or not it is a package usage issue or a programming issue.  Why is it trying to open that?  Part of the thing likes like a base64 string.

pls check the question its now edited and updated

im using 3 packages only i think the problem is related to flutter_inappwebview and  flutter_widget_from_html
bcoz without flutter_inappwebview youtube wont able to run so i suspect using both is the problem
thanks for replying im new to stack over flow will learn how to post a question cleary and understandble .
